# Preventing move base from executing a queued-up goal

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem where I have a set of goals sent to my (physical) robot every few seconds , from a subscriber's callback. The robot is slow and takes a while to reach the next goal. By this time, a huge list of goals have piled up in the action client's queue.

**How can I get only the last goal (i.e. the one at the tail end of the queue) to execute?**

I want to drop all intermediate goals.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12085/preventing-move-base-from-executing-a-queued-up-goal/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2012-01-16**:
using actionlib

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-04**:
How are you setting the goals? Using an actionlib client or just using move_base_simple/goal topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Extracted from here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Subscriber_Options

```
template<class M>
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, 
<callback, which may involve multiple arguments>, const ros::TransportHints&
transport_hints = ros::TransportHints());
```

You can set the queue size for receiving the messages, if you have a queue size of 1, you will only store the latest message

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1